# Can't use vsjitdebugger anymore to debug processes at startup

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-10

When I was working in versions of windows prior to Windows 10, I was able to get the debugger to be invoked when a particular executable was started.  To do this I created the following batch file:

```cmd
@echo off
 >%temp%\output.reg echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>>%temp%\output.reg echo+
>>%temp%\output.reg echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\regsvr32.exe]
>>%temp%\output.reg echo "debugger"="vsjitdebugger.exe"
regedit /s %temp%\output.reg
del %temp\output.reg
```

And to stop it I used:

```cmd
@echo off
 >%temp%\output.reg echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>>%temp%\output.reg echo+
>>%temp%\output.reg echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\regsvr32.exe]
>>%temp%\output.reg echo "debugger"=-
regedit /s %temp%\output.reg
del %temp\output.reg
```

Of course these files are used exclusively for `regsvr32.exe`.  I have others for other executables.

However, when using this trick under Windows 10, it failed to work.  I would get the error:

> An error occurred while launching 'regsvr32 "my.dll"':
>
> The Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger was not notified that the application correctly started.
>
> Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.

I don't know what documentation index that it was referring to, but I figured that it was some permission issue, so I tried to change the settings on the `vsjitdebugger.exe` file to `Run this program as an administrator`, to which I got a different error dialog that said:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32\regsvr32.exe
>
> The requested operation requires elevation.

Now, if I were to open up a Administrator cmd window and use the command:

```
vsjitdebugger.exe regsvr32  "my.dll"
```

This does invoke the debugger at start up of the `regsvr32.exe` application.  However, the point of this trick was to ensure that the debugger gets invoked when anything executes the application, which may not be under a cmd process that I am controlling.

So I have 2 questions.

1. Does anyone know of the document index that is being referred to in the error message?
2. How do I get this to work under Windows 10 Version 1709 (OS Build 16299.371)?

Comment: IMHO it should still work. Use SysInternals Process Monitor and check what it does.

Comment: Still doesn't work with Windows 11 and VS 2022 Enterprise installed. None of the AeDebug or WER troubleshooting tips help. One thing I have found that does work is that if you launch the application you want to debug as administrator, then it works.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. No idea why, but apparently on Windows 10 it's necessary to configure something in the registry, which as far as I remember wasn't necessary before, or maybe happened automatically when installing Visual Studio.

It's mentioned here under "troubleshooting": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger#jit_errors

```
The fix is to add a DWORD Value of Auto, with Value data of 1, to the following registry keys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug

(For 64-bit machines): HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

Comment: Four years later, and that known issue apparently still exists ...